# Including an image with Three.js

Tags: javascript, image, three.js

I'm actually trying to include a .jpg image into my 3D scene. All solutions i have found consisted in apply those images on meshes as texture : but then the scene does not look like well. Indeed, we can see the mesh border whether it be a plane or sphere... I just want to see the image. Does exist it another solution ?
On my application, i want to rotate an airplane around the earth, and the problem is about including this airplane.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you included some code you've tried (jsfiddle+), or images of 1) how it now looks like 2) what it should look like. Not sure what you are looking for but I'd quess you may want to play with material.transparent = true and maybe use png with alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the class THREE.Sprite will accomplish the effect you want.  THREE.Sprite can display an image, and can use either screen coordinates (e.g. canvas coordinates) or it can be part of your 3D scene, but a sprite image is always facing the camera.  If you want the image to rotate, you do need to use it as a texture on a mesh.  Whatever you decide to do in the end, I've posted a bunch of tutorial-style examples at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ that may help. Good luck!

Comment: I have seen some THREE.Sprite examples and indeed, images are rotating facing the camera, it is therefore a 2D model but it helped me so much because i would use it for others situations :) Concerning my 3D problem, i have decided to replace my jpg image to png image, i can then adjust it more easily. That is not a real solution but it at least removes all "borders" which were be overdrawn on another mesh. Thank you for your answer